# I created a csv file. Then retrieves the content as key-value. What's the best way to update the values with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I created a csv file. Then retrieves the content as key-value. What's the best way to update the values with CodeIgniter?

Comment: you really need to show us some evidence of your research so we know what you might have tried/not tried.  As it stands your question is far too broad.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here the part of my file creation:

$fileName = '/home/clemjon/Desktop/testListings/'.$listingId.'.csv';
            $fp = fopen($fileName, 'r');
            $fields = fgetcsv($fp); 

            $result = array();

            while ($record = fgetcsv($fp))
            {
                $result[] = array_combine($fields, $record);
            }

            $sess_array = array();
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $sess_array = array(
                    'current_listing_id' => $row['listing_id'],
                    'listing_description' =>$row['description'],
                    'current_listing_min_age' => $row['min_age'],
                    'current_listing_max_age' => $row['max_age'],
                    'current_listing_contact_id' => $row['contact_id']
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_array);
            }
```